# I need help traversing some XML using XLST and extracting the data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML and am required to extract the data using XLST.
I need to pull out the data in pairs via Name, Description with their respective values for output in XLST.

### So..

txt_name, Jonathan Smith

txt_description, Man

---

txt_name, Mary Smith

txt_description, Woman

---

Here is the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dfor:form-data xmlns:dfor="http://kana.com/dforms">
    <dfor:field>
        <dfor:name>eml_email</dfor:name>
        <dfor:value>email@email.com</dfor:value>
    </dfor:field>
    <dfor:field>
        <dfor:name>otom_children</dfor:name>
        <dfor:children>
            <dfor:child>
                <dfor:field>
                    <dfor:name>txt_name</dfor:name>
                    <dfor:value>Mary Smith</dfor:value>
                </dfor:field>
                <dfor:field>
                    <dfor:name>txt_description</dfor:name>
                    <dfor:value>Woman</dfor:value>
                </dfor:field>
            </dfor:child>
            <dfor:child>
                <dfor:field>
                    <dfor:name>txt_name</dfor:name>
                    <dfor:value>Jonathan Smith</dfor:value>
                </dfor:field>
                <dfor:field>
                    <dfor:name>txt_description</dfor:name>
                    <dfor:value>Man</dfor:value>
                </dfor:field>
            </dfor:child>
        </dfor:children>
    </dfor:field>
</dfor:form-data>
```

I have tried traversing using "<xsl:for-each select=" but am unable to get it working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be more specific, please? Can you edit your question in order to add 1) your code, and 2) the expected output corresponding to your input file above? This is the way this forum is working.

Comment: Is there any reason that Jonathan Smith is output before Mary Smith, being in the reverse order in the input file?

Comment: It was an error when typing up the question, the data is as shown in answer - Thanks

Comment: I would also like to know how to use the outer XSL loop to only return the children for
'  <dfor:field>
        <dfor:name>otom_children</dfor:name>'
otom_children, as I now have multiple child elements which belong to different parent.

Comment: I advise you to post a new question for that second problem in order to be seen by a large amount of users.

Comment: I did @PierreFrançois Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dfor="http://kana.com/dforms">

  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//dfor:child"><!-- outer loop -->
      <xsl:for-each select="dfor:field"><!-- inner loop -->
        <xsl:value-of select="dfor:name"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="dfor:value"/>
        <xsl:text><!-- output new line -->
</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text><!-- output 1 extra new line after the inner loop -->
</xsl:text>    
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your help, I had real problems with this and it was far easier than I imagined.